# Creating a Search Form using a Combo Box in ms-Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

Goal: I want to create a custom form to filter data from a table. I have a combo box which is used to select filter criteria and then generate a subform with the desired filtered data.

Here is my code for populating the subform with the filter criteria only if a specific field matches my selected combo box value.

```
Private Sub comboBox_selection_AfterUpdate()
Dim Filter_Function As String
Filter_Function = "SELECT * FROM mainTable WHERE ([Specific_Field] = " & Me.comboBox_selection & ")"
Me.Some_subform.Form.RecordSource = Filter_Function
Me.Some_subform.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

Results: When I select criteria from the combo box, I receive the message

> "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression
> '([Specific_field] = comboBox_selection)'"

When I try to debug the code, it highlights the line

`Me.Some_subform.Form.RecordSource = Filter_Function`

with a yellow arrow pointing to it.

Additional Info:

1. The table that is used to generate the combo box values comes from a different table "Another_Table", not the mainTable
2. The mainTable field that I am using as the field to check the matching combo box selection is also a combo box pulling options from the same "Another_Table"

I am very new to VBA and coding in general, so I can tell that the error is probably something basic that I just have not learned yet. I triple checked all my spelling and punctuation, so I am quite confident that is not the issue (unless there is some weird rules saying I cannot capitalize my table/form names).

I tried to find the answer on my own for the last couple of days, but failed.

If someone could point me in the right direction, It would be much appreciated.

Comment: Edit question to show combobox RowSource SQL. What data type is [Specific_Field]? Instead of setting RecordSource, could probably just set Filter and FilterOn properties.

Comment: I am not sure what a "RowSource SQL" is.
My combo box says "RowSource" in "Data" is = SELECT [cbox_table].[cbox_field] FROM cbox_table ORDER BY [cbox_field];
hope this helps

The data type for [Specific_Field] is Short Text, but it is also a combo box. It pulls data from the [cbox_table]![cbox_field]

Comment: That is an SQL statement directly in RowSource property - as opposed to a table or query object name. You have table named `cbox_table`? Odd name and not informative. What data is in this table?

Comment: My appologies; you are correct, I have a `cbox_table` table that just has a short text field. The sole purpose of this table is to have an easily editable means of generating a combo box. So I use this table to pull data from to generate my combo box pull down options.
Did I answer your first question above? `"Show combobox RowSource SQL"`

Comment: Yes but what is this data - people, cars, fruit? This table is called a 'lookup' table. A single field table is less common but not odd, just tables usually have more informative names. Yes, that did answer question. Do you understand my explanation?

Comment: The data is just a type of extraction (I work in a hospital lab in toxicology) so the extraction type is just a name of a drug or standard that we purchase. E.g. `opiate` or `amphetamine`.
I plan on trying your suggestion now for the Filter and FilterOn properties, once I do a bit more research on this function (just so I understand it better). Thank you and @Harun24HR

Comment: Then why not `tblExtractionTypes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @June7 suggested you can try `FilterOn` property. I would also suggest you to use `after_update` event.

```
Dim Filter_Function As String

Filter_Function = "[Specific_Field] ='" & Me.cboSearch & "'"

Forms![MyFormName]![Some_subform].Form.FilterOn = False
Forms![MyFormName]![Some_subform].Form.Filter = Filter_Function
Forms![MyFormName]![Some_subform].Form.FilterOn = True
```

Comment: I'll give this a try today, thank you for the suggestion.
It also seems that my syntax is a bit off. I will update later today.
Thanks!

Comment: As shown, apostrophe delimiters are needed around parameters for text fields. Use # for date/time type and nothing for number type.

Answer (score 0):

I did use an `After_Update` event along with the the code provided above by @Harun24HR.

Thank you both @June7 and @Harun24HR, this was both incredibly informative and helpful. The `Filter and FilterOn` function worked perfectly. I believe I understand how this function works now, and why there is three lines of code for it (in terms of order operation?). It is much more concise than my first attempt.

I think I need to visit some more tutorials for basic VBA for access.

Comment: In my code first `FilterOn=False` will clear filters if already have any filters to that subform. Then second libe will set filter and third line will execute filtering. So, if found the answer helpful then please consider accepting my answer (tick mark it) so that others people know that this solve your problem and the question will be treated as solved to this community.

Comment: My apologies! I did not know that was how it was done. Thank you. I should have paid closer attention to everything on the screen.